# In Eclipse, a way to see code errors without moving the mouse?

Tags: eclipse

I've programmed in Emacs for a while, and I'm starting to learn Java in Eclipse. I prefer not to have to take my hands off the keyboard in order to see errors that Eclipse marks in the code... so I'd rather not hover over them, (plus the red X on the left margin is annoyingly small and hard to target for a hover)... is there a way to get them to pop up simply by moving the cursor to that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Show Tooltip Description" command usually has the keybinding of **F2**. You can change it on the **Keys** preference page if you like.